# Subplot boxplot Seaborn in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a unique figure after a for loop. I would like to get one plot containing subplots for each columns.
With the following code I obtain a plot for each column in the last box (see figure)

```
for i in commonSC12:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(11,11)
    sns.set()
    sns.set(style="whitegrid")
    sns.boxplot(x='ConVar', y=i, data=dff,width=0.3, palette='Dark2')  
    fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Create the figure outside of the loop. Loop through `comminSC12` and the axes at the same time (using [`zip`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)). Then use the `ax=` argument of [seaborn's boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)

Comment: This would be better with something `FaceGrid`.

Comment: I think the for loop is perfectly fine here, and probably easier than reformatting the data to use `FacetGrid`, but it is necessary (as @DavidG says) to do the figure setup *outside* the loop.